# R Shiny: Storing reactive datasets into a list and access them through radiobutton selection

Tags: r, shiny

I'll keep this simple. I'm building a shiny app that loads data from a file and then creates a dataset. That dataset can then be processed, resulting in another one.

What I would like my app to do is store the first dataset and each time a new dataset is created store it as well. According to the list of saved datasets a radiobuttons UI would then be created so that the user could be able to choose a dataset to work with.

The problem is, when I run the app and load the file (creating the first dataset) the place where the UI should appear shows an error: `'Error: subscript out of bounds'` and if I try to apply a function to the current dataset (`dataset.current()`) it says the dataset is NULL, which means, of course, that my code isn't doing what it is supposed to.

Everything else in the app is working (e.g. dataset creation from file).

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Below is some code from the server.R script (only the important parts):

```
(...)
#list to store the datasets
datasets.list = list()

#adds first dataset created to the list
observe({
  if(length(datasets.list) < 1 & !is.null(dataset())){
    datasets.list[['dataset()']] = dataset()
  }
})

#renders the UI according to the stored datasets
output$datasets1 <- renderUI({
   radioButtons('datasets', 'Selected dataset:', choices = names(datasets.list[]))
})

#the current dataset the user is working with according to the selection
dataset.current <- reactive ({
   if (length(datasets.list) > 0 & !is.null(dataset())){
      return(datasets.list[[input$datasets]])
   }
})
(...)  

#(e.g.) Applying background correction to the current dataset, creating another one
dataset.bg <- reactive({
   input$preprocess
   isolate({
     if (!is.null(dataset()) & input$pMethods == 'bgCor') {
        return (data_correction(dataset.current(),"background"))
     }
   })
})

#Add created dataset to list
observe({
   if(!is.null(dataset.bg())){
      datasets.list[['dataset.bg()']] = dataset.bg()
    }
})
```

Comment: It's hard to debug a non-reproducible example, but I suggest use `reactiveValues` for your list and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately I'll only have a chance to work on this again in a couple days, but I will try your suggestion and let you know if it worked!  Thank you  :)

Comment: Using `reactiveValues` as you suggested worked, thank you :)